# How can my consumer keep reading all the messages from RabbitMQ and then reply the producer (RPC) when the number of messages are greater than n?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rpc

I've a consumer for rabbitmq that reads from a particular queue and does some operation.
Now I want to perform that operation in a batch. I am unable to figure out a way where the consumer would just save the whole context in a list, i.e. (ch, method, props, body) and then when the size is greater than 'n', that is the required minimum batch size, I can perform the batch operation and do something like:

```
if len(no_of_messages) > 10:
    responses = batch_operation(messages)
    for response in responses:
        ch, method, props, body = response
        ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                         routing_key=props.reply_to,
                         properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                             correlation_id=props.correlation_id),
                         body=str(body))
```

Any idea on how to go about it? I am starting the consumer like this:

```
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(some_function_that_does_above_stuffs, queue='rpc_queue')

print(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests")
channel.start_consuming()
```